# How does a compound lens produce both an enlarged image and a reduced image?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Imagine placing a compound lens (two convex lenses, +150 mm and +75 mm focal lengths separated by 3 mm) between a light source and a screen. In the lab, I adjusted the position of the compound lens so that when it is closer to the screen, an in-focus reduced sized image forms on the screen. I then positioned the compound lens so that it was closer to the source and found an in-focus enlarged image. The source and the screen remained in the same position the entire time. How can we explain the formation of two in-focus images at different lens positions?

Comment: Hint: when the image is in focus, what would happen if you were to swap the light source and the screen? There is a focal length measurement technique called Bessel's method that relies on your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a position for which the image is in-focus. If you reverse the position of the object and the image, the principle of inverse return indicates that the two are still conjugate to each other. It is therefore normal that you find two sharp positions symmetrical with respect to the middle of the object-image axis.

It is also easy to understand that if the magnification is greater than 1 in the first case, it will be less than 1 in the second (The magnifications are reversed)

In the case of a thin lens, the calculation is very easy and we find that, for a screen-object distance of $D$, the focal length of the lens must be less than $D/4$ so that we can have an image. And there are indeed two possible positions of the lens. This is Bessel's method to get the focal length.

If the focal length is exactly $D/4$, there is only one position left in the middle (Position $2f, 2f$). This is Silberman's method of obtaining the focal length.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

The effect that you have noticed of there being two positions for a converging lens system to form a real image on a screen when the object and screen are not moved relative to one another occurs as long as the separation between the object and the screen is greater than four time the focal length of the lens system.

The ray diagram which illustrate this is shown below with the separation of object and screen being $D$ and the movement of the lens system $x$.

[image]

Rays $1$ and $2$ locate the image $I_1$ and when the lens system is moved  a distance $x$, rays $3$ and $4$ locate the image $I_2$

It is the basis of the "displacement method" of measuring the focal length $f$ of a lens system as it can be shown that $f = \dfrac{D^2-x^2}{4D}$.

Comment: Thank you for the ray diagram. I found out through deriving the equation you provided that the object distance,  $d_o = \pm\sqrt{D^{2}-4fD}$ which I'm assuming is why there are 2 positions.